# does command-option-click on app icon in dock still hide all open windows?

Tags: macos, dock

[This](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2307) apple article explains it.

But it no longer hides all open windows for me under 10.7.4. What could be causing this?

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand the command.  Command-Option-Click on an app icon hides all open windows from apps other than the one you click on.  For the record, I have just tested that this still works.

Answer (score 1):

`Command-option-click` does not hide all open windows. As stated in the linked Apple article, this command hides all *other* open items leaving the clicked item visible. It is possible to hide all other items and minimize your most recently item with `command+option+h+m`. This is a combination of `command+option+h` - Hide Others and `command+option+m` - Minimize.